# What's wrong with this mysql import?

Tags: mysql

The dump file was created by phpMyAdmin. I'm having problems with importing it to my local MySQL server. Seems like this line is causing issues:

```
PRIMARY KEY (`arid`)
```

**Dump file header**

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.0.8
-- Server version: 5.5.32-cll
-- PHP Version: 5.3.17
```

**Local MySQL version**

```
innodb_version: 1.1.8
protocol_version: 10
version: 5.5.17
```

**Dump file reduced to bare minimum**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ar` (
    `arid` int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`arid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

**Update**

This is getting strange...

1. This command works via MySQL prompt.

   create table `ar` (`arid` int(11) not null);
2. I delete the table.
3. I put that same command (Ctrl+V) into the dump file. The dump file only has that command.
4. Using DOS prompt, I navigate to the folder with the dump file and execute `type file.sql`. DOS prompt confirms that file only has the command from step 1.
5. When I try to import it, I get "You have an error in your sql syntax"

Comment: Judging by error message you have a syntax error in your `admin_WebSiteAdmin.sql` file

Comment: Can you post the content from admin_WebSiteAdmin file?

Comment: That file was generated by phpMyAdmin. I created an InnoDB database on my hosting provider and added tables with indexes and referential integrity. Then I exported the file and now I'm trying to import it to my local MySQL so I can code locally against it. There's no data there.

Comment: We need to see full error message and corresponding part of the file

Comment: it just tells me "you have an error in your sql... check the manual... at line 1". Anyways, it seems to have a problem with `PRIMARY KEY (`arid`)`.

Comment: Please do not delete the contents of your question in this manner.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in your sql file. One of the SQL queries present in the **admin_WebSiteAdmin.sql** file has an error.

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell us mysql version that you have on your host and mysql on your local machine?

Most likely than not, reason for this error is incompatibilities between versions.